# How can i make character walking when pressing W key and idle/grounded when stop pressing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CC : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private Animator _anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();   
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            _anim.Play("Walk");
        }
        else
        {
            _anim.Play("Grounded");
        }
    }
}
```

When i just did:

```
_anim.Play("Walk");
```

The character is walking nonstop forward.
But now i want to make him walk when i press holding down W and when not pressing W to be idle/grounded.

But it's not working the character is moving without walking.

The script is attached to a third person character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are translating the transform even if 'w' is not pressed. Move the translation inside the if case and everything will work as planned. Additionally `GetKeyDown` should be substituted with `GetKey` and the current state should be saved, as the Definition for the first one is:

> You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again. - [Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

Code could look like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CC : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private Animator _anim;
    private bool _isWalking = false;

    private void Start()
    {
         _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();   
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            if(!_isWalking)
            {
                _isWalking = true;
                _anim.Play("Walk");
            }
            var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;
            transform.Translate(0, 0, z); // Only move when "w" is pressed.
        }
        else
        {
            if(_isWalking)
            {
                _anim.Play("Grounded");
            }
            _isWalking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, It's working fine. How can i make something that will change smooth between the two states from Walk to Idle and from Idle to Walk ? Now when i press W or leave the W it's switching at once to the other state. Maybe some slow down then switch to idle ?

Comment: I imagine you could remember how long ago you started to press the button and using the passed time to see how fast you go. For example, right at pressing the speed is 1/100th of the full speed, while after 0.5 seconds you are at 50%. Next Thing would be to adjust your animation logic accordingly. But that seems like a different question and I didn't work enough with Unity3d in the last year to be able to correctly answer that.

Answer (score 1):

`update()` is called on every new frame, but the `getKeyDown()` method only returns true during the frame in which the user presses the button. Since you kept pressing the w-Key the statement returned false and the  "grounded" block gets executed.

Try to start the animation on `Input.GetKeyDown()` but only change the animation to idle with `Input.GetKeyUp();`